# Can't update device firmware for Dell XPS 9310 Ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, dell

I get this error message:

> Unable to update "Secure Boot dbx Configuration update": Blocked executable in the ESP, ensure grub and shim are up to date...

[image: pop up with error message]

What do I do next? Do I have to reinstall Ubuntu?

Comment: Seems related to this fwupdmgr issue.
https://github.com/fwupd/fwupd/issues/5035

Comment: I ran `sudo fwupdmgr update`, but still get the same 'blocked executable in the ESP' error. The more frustrating thing is I can't find anything on the internet about that error.

Comment: Still getting this error: `Blocked executable in the ESP, ensure grub and shim are up to date: /boot/efi/efi.factory/boot/bootx64.efi Authenticode checksum [2ea4cb6a1f1eb1d3dce82d54fde26ded243ba3e18de7c6d211902a594fe56788] is present in dbx
`

Comment: This post gives a useful summary of the issue: https://github.com/fwupd/fwupd/wiki/Blocked-executable-in-the-ESP,-ensure-grub-and-shim-are-up-to-date

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem. After some research I think the issue is that some Dell laptops have old bootloaders that are not used but are now marked as insecure.

There is a [useful summary](https://github.com/fwupd/fwupd/wiki/Blocked-executable-in-the-ESP,-ensure-grub-and-shim-are-up-to-date) of the issue in the `fwupd` wiki and a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/dell/+bug/1990179) that has some useful suggestions.

The answer appears to be to identify and remove the old insecure bootloaders.

**Please take these steps with caution as it could make your system unbootable.**

In my case the error was:

> Blocked executable in the ESP, ensure grub and shim are up to date: /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/shimx64.efi Authenticode checksum [47b31a1c7867644b2ee8093b2d5fbe21e21f77c1617a2c08812f57ace0850e9f] is present in db

By running `sudo ls -al /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/` I could see that this file dated from 2017 so was quite old (much older than the other files in this directory).

I checked that this file wasn't in use by running `efibootmgr -v` and checking for references to this file.

Once I was sure that it was old and unused, I took a backup and then removed the file (`sudo rm /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/shimx64.efi`).

I was then able to update the device firmware with `fwupdmgr update` (or you could use the Ubuntu Software Centre).

Comment: i'm trying these steps but failing: 

```~$ ls -al /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/ ls: cannot access '/boot/efi/EFI/Boot/': Permission denied```

Comment: ```~$ sudo rm /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/shimx64.efi

rm: cannot remove '/boot/efi/EFI/Boot/shimx64.efi': No such file or directory```

Comment: You need `sudo` in front of the first command. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I don't think your issue is exactly the same as mine so you probably don't need to remove the same file. As I said I would be careful about running the above commands and don't recommend copying and pasting them blindly without understanding what you are doing. You could leave your system in an unbootable state. It sounds like the answer from @mikbini is closer to what you need to do.

Answer (score 5):

Thought I would add my tuppence on this, as it appears this issue (`Secure Boot dbx Configuration Update`  being shown over an over and being blocked from a simple update) has been happening a lot (and  not just on the dell machine mentioned, mine is an Asus laptop), and there was one solution I managed to use that allowed the simplest set of steps to resolve the issue:
simply use a variation of `sudo fwupdmgr update` as that command will cause an attempt that fails, because there has been some partial or complete update but the update has remained flagged incorrectly, therefore thought I would try

```
sudo fwupdmgr update --force
```

and that seems to have done the trick, update gone from my update list, all notifications stopped and the issue with the update itself seems to be resolved, whilst the system is now fully operational and stable.  Hope this helps someone else to resolve this too.

Comment: thanks, your solution does work in my case.

Comment: thanks for confirming, I am always wary in case I have made some odd unique config and the solution I post is unique to me: so it is great to get confirmation :D

Comment: Did the job for me to fix the exact same issue with Lenovo Thinkpad P52 laptop

Answer (score 2):

I believe this means that the hash for your existing bootloader (bootx64.efi) is in the dbx you are trying to install. If you were to succeed with the installation of the newer dbx, and Secure Boot is enabled, your system will halt during boot because bootx64.efi is not trusted by Secure Boot.

I think the advice its giving you, to update to the latest version of shim and grub, is really solid.

You can update the dbx manually, but use caution as you can lock yourself out of the system (e.g. if you have a BIOS password set, but forget what that password is, you won't be able to boot your system!).

I wrote a post that explains how all this works, including how to update teh dbx manually (again use extreme caution), hope it helps: https://eclypsium.com/2022/07/26/firmware-security-realizations-part-1-secure-boot-and-dbx/

Comment: For now I'm waiting on the fwupdmgr 1.8.5 update, hopefully that resolves the issue.

Comment: If you search the hash "2ea4cb6a1f1eb1d3dce82d54fde26ded243ba3e18de7c6d211902a594fe56788" from your output in this document: https://uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/dbx_info_2020_2022.pdf you see it was "shim64-bit.efi" hash that was revoked due to a number of CVEs (that are listed in that document)

Comment: Is the lower risk thing to update the shim & grub and how are those done?

Comment: Could you explain the difference between grub/shim and dbx?

Comment: Without a word on how to update grub and shim - I can't like this answer.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with the denylisted `bootx64.efi` in `/boot/efi/efi.factory` but at least in my case it looks like it wasn't actually used:

```
$ efibootmgr |grep '^Boot[0-9]*[*]'|sed -e 's/[*] .*//g'|while read i; do efibootdump $i | echo "$i:" `sed -e 's/^.*File(\([^)]*\)).*$/\1/g'`; done
Boot0000: \EFI\Boot\BootX64.efi
Boot0002: \EFI\PEBoot\bootx64.efi
Boot0003: \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi
Boot0005: \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi
$
```

I'm far from being an EFI expert but I thought that if it's not used in any boot config then I don't need it.

So I checked that I have a recovery USB drive around, I moved it somewhere under /home just in case, removed it from /boot/efi/efi.factory and rebooted. And fwupdmgr was able to update the DBX.

Scavenging around, on my system (a Dell XPS 13) the recovery partition has 2 identical mountable FAT images (boot/efi.img and boot/grub/efi.img) and they both contain a byte-identical copy of the denylisted file under efi/boot/bootx64.efi).

So my guess is that the laptop shipped with the now denylisted bootx64.efi and some ultra-cautious installer moved the existing EFI configuration to the efi.factory folder before replacing it with its own stuff. But I think nothing in the `efi.factory` the folder is actually needed.

Comment: Could you describe actual steps for me to take?

Comment: If I screw this up, can I recover using a USB recovery drive to reinstall Ubuntu?

Comment: Suggested repair:  ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would reinstall the grub-efi-amd64-signed of
nvme0n1p3,
using the following options:  nvme0n1p1/boot/efi
Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s use-standard-efi-file  

what command would I run for this?